# Implementing PDFKIT but no Rakefile found

Tags: ruby, bash

I'm following a railscast, but there is a stage where it asks to bash:

```
rake middleware
```

When I run this command it says 'no Rakefile found'. Looking through my files I see warble.rake and version.rake but no others. Could someone explain where I am going wrong or where I could find this or whether I need to create it. If so where?

Comment: It is looking for an actual Rakefile. It expects that file to pull in all other .rake files into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using rails, then there should be a file named 'Rakefile' in the root of your project, this usually looks like this:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

AppName::Application.load_tasks
```

Suggest you create it if it's not there.

If you're not using rails, you'll need to add a Rakefile and manually require the tasks within it (also remove the ruby-on-rails tag from your question)